# Shortest path between each node in the graph and elements in a list

Tags: python, networkx

The following dataframe

```
Node       Target
Jennifer   Maria
Luke       Mark
Johnny     Martin
Ludo       Martin
Maria      nan
Mark       Luke
Mark       Christopher
```

is used for building a network (where node is the source node):

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, source='Node', target='Target')
```

I would like to list all the shortest path (if they exist) between the source node and nodes that are in a separate list:

```
list4path=['Christopher', 'Donna', 'Julian','Martin']
```

There are several options for calculating the shortest path in networkx (e.g., shortest_path), but I am wondering how I can get all the shortest path between each node and the several targets in the `list4pth` (the Target column needs only for building purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the default behavior of `nx.shortest_path(G)` when no `source` or `target` arguments are specified as long as your network is small-ish.  If you just run `all_shortest = nx.shortest_path(G)`, per the [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx-algorithms-shortest-paths-generic-shortest-path):

> If neither the source nor target are specified return a dictionary of dictionaries with path[source][target]=[list of nodes in path].

Then `all_shortest['Luke']['Christopher']` will be **a** shortest path between Luke and Christopher or will result in a `KeyError` if there is no path between the nodes.  Or you could use `.get()` to avoid the `KeyError`.

If your network is large enough that it's more practical to only calculate paths with targets in `list4path`, then you could do something like this:

```
selected_shortest = {source: {target: nx.shortest_path(G, source, target) for target in list4path if nx.has_path(G, source, target)} for source in G.nodes()}
```

which would give you the same data structure but only calculate the desired shortest paths ending in a node from `list4path`.

I'm sure it would be *much* faster to write a simple function that just handles the case where there is no path between `source` and `target`.  I just called the extra `nx.has_path()` function in a lazily written one-liner, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader to optimize. ;^)