# Shortest paths and dictionary

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

I have the following shortest paths

```
{'A': {'B': ['A', 'B'],
  'A': ['A'],
  'C': ['A', 'C']},
 'D': {'A': ['D', 'A'],
  'B': ['D', 'B'],
  'C': ['D', 'C']}}
```

built as follows:

```
selected_shortest = {source: {target: nx.shortest_path(G, source, target) for target in list4path if nx.has_path(G, source, target)} for source in G.nodes()}
```

where G is a network

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, source='Node', target='Target')
```

and `list4path` is a list of potential targets(e.g., A,B and C).
I would like to get, instead of the name of nodes between the source and the target in the list, the distance (or separation) between them. So, for example,

```
{'A': {'B': 1,
  'A': 0
  'C': 1},
 'D': {'A': 1,
  'B': 1,
  'C': 1}}
```

in order to take the average of these calculated shortest paths.
Could you please help me to get these values for average?

Comment: Seems like you could just set all the list values to len(list)-1, no?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to replace `shortest_path` by `shortest_path_length`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
for node in selected_shortest:
  for key in selected_shortest[node]:
    selected_shortest[node][key] = len(selected_shortest[node][key]) - 1
```

Comment: Hi Chaos_Is_Harmony, I am getting this error: `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` when I run this: `----> 3     selected_shortest[node][key] = len(selected_shortest[node][key]) - 1` . I checked and selected_shortest has values. How can I visualize the results generated by the for loop?

Comment: So you're saying ```selected_shortest[node][key]``` returns an ```int``` and not a ```list```? If that's the case, the dict of dicts you have at the beginning of the question isn't accurately representing what ```selected_shortest``` actually is...

Comment: adding the square brackets, it does not recognize target. I am following the solution proposed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68801210/shortest-path-between-each-node-in-the-graph-and-elements-in-a-list

Comment: Yeah, ```nx.shortest_path()``` must already return a list...

Comment: Given the error message, I wonder if ```nx.shortest_path(G, source, target) for target in list4path if nx.has_path(G, source, target)``` returns an ``int``` instead of a ```list``` in some cases...?

Comment: I have checked but it seems it returns all lists, no int. I have not got any error when I tried the solution from the other post, so I guess there might be  a problem somewhere in the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236169/discussion-between-chaos-is-harmony-and-v-sqrt).